Unable to transcode h264 to hevc on Ubuntu 24.04.1
I am attempting to transcode an h.264 video to h.265 using ffmpeg and Intel Quick Sync
hardware.
hwinfo:
str3: "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz"
lsb_release -a:
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
mediainfo:
Codec ID                                 : mp4v-20
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
ffmpeg -encoders:
V..... hevc_qsv             HEVC (Intel Quick Sync Video acceleration) (codec hevc)
ffmpeg -decoders:
V....D h264_qsv             H264 video (Intel Quick Sync Video acceleration) (codec h264)
So, it looks like I have QSV support for both decoding and encoding this video.
command:
ffmpeg -c:v h264_qsv -i $1 -c:v hevc_qsv -c:a copy $2
output:
[h264 @ 0x5e67e9970b80] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0x5e67e9970b80] no frame!

... (jillions of these)

[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5e67e996e440] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Video: h264 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), none, 3948 kb/s): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2013-08-07T20:53:52.000000Z
  Duration: 00:12:08.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4058 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 106 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-07T20:53:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Video: h264 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), none, 3948 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-07T20:53:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_qsv) -> hevc (hevc_qsv))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
libva info: VA-API version 1.20.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_20
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0

[h264_qsv @ 0x5e67e9b574c0] Error creating a MFX session: -9.
[h264_qsv @ 0x5e67e9b574c0] Error initializing an MFX session
[h264_qsv @ 0x5e67e9b574c0] Error decoding header
[vist#0:1/h264 @ 0x5e67e9976700] Error submitting packet to decoder: Unknown error occurred

... (jillions of these)

[vist#0:1/h264 @ 0x5e67e9976700] Decoding error: Invalid argument
[h264_qsv @ 0x5e67e9b574c0] [IMGUTILS @ 0x706ba89fecb0] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[h264_qsv @ 0x5e67e9b574c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[h264_qsv @ 0x5e67e9b574c0] get_buffer() failed

... (jillions of these)

[h264_qsv @ 0x5e67e9b574c0] Too many errors when draining, this is a bug. Stop draining and force EOF.
[vist#0:1/h264 @ 0x5e67e9976700] Decoding error: Internal bug, should not have happened
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:1 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
[vist#0:1/h264 @ 0x5e67e9976700] Decode error rate 1 exceeds maximum 0.666667
[out#0/mp4 @ 0x5e67e9973cc0] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:54.98 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=6.86x
Exiting normally, received signal 2.

I killed the process after a while because no output was being written.
I've successfully used QSV to transcode this video before, on an earlier version of Kubuntu, and I do not remember having to install any missing packages.  The original file plays just fine on mplayer and VLC. I can transcode the file with libx265 software transcoding and get no errors. This is not the only file with a problem -  I cannot get any
files to transcode h254->h265 using QSV on Ubuntu 24.04.1.
I've installed intel-media-va-driver-non-free and libmfx-gen1.2 (? just in case) and did a
sudo apt update (nothing updated).
"Internal bug, should not have happened" doesn't sound like operator error. Should I report a bug? Or else, what can I do?
Thanks in advance,
-Stuart
